# Change size of window dialogs in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

In a Sitecore 6.5 solution, is it possible to change the default size of a window dialog in the backend? For instance a "Insert link" dialog?
I have a rather large solution with many items, and with the current size of the window, there quickly shows horisontal scrollbars in the tree-side, because of all the levels.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this be changed through the contentManager.css file?